# Why doesn't RouterLink take you to the top of the new page but a regular HTML link does when both compile to the same HTML?

Tags: angular-dart, angular-dart-routing

I have `<router-outlet [routes]="Routes.all"></router-outlet>` set in my app component. I have a page with links at the bottom of the page. If a user clicks a link I want them to be taken to the top of the new page.

If I use RouterLink the current scroll position is retained so the user lands in the middle of the new page.

`<a [routerLink]="RoutePaths.featurePage.toUrl()">...</a>`

If I use a regular HTML link, I get the behavior I want, the user lands at the top of the new page.

`<a href="/feature-page">...</a>`

What I really don't get is how they can respond differently yet compile to the exact same HTML code.

`<a class="_ngcontent-zbb-0" href="/feature-page">...</a>`

What am I missing here?

I understand regular non-Dart Angular has something called `scrollPositionRestoration` but it doesn't seem to exist for AngularDart.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is really a hack to return the scroll position by utilizing the

`window.scrollTo(x,y)` function.

This issue was raised in here in regular angular
[Equivalent to autoscroll=true: automatic scroll to top when route changes](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6946)

> remmeber to import dart:html